# How is crosswalk licensend?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I am building my app with framework 7 and phonegap. I have some issues on some devices. I found the solution for this is using crosswalk. Does crosswalk have some copyright to prevent distribution of my app?

Comment: Seems like licensing questions would best be answered by the developers of Crosswalk.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [FAQ](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Commercial-aspects) helps:

> Do I have to pay for the Crosswalk Project?
>
> No, Crosswalk is an opensource project, hosted on github, and licensed under the BSD licence.
> It is free to use for any purpose, commercial or otherwise.